# What rollback actually does?

Tags: java, database, jdbc

I trying to find out what rollback actually does.

I have couple of scenarios:

1. Rolling back after a successful commit.

   ```
   Connection conn=getConnection();
   try{
      executesSomeQuery(conn);
      conn.commit();
   } catch(Exception e){
      //assume no exception
   }finally{
      conn.rollback();
   }
   ```
2. Rolling back after an unsuccessful commit. If committing three queries q1, q2, q3 in order within the same `commit()`, what happens to q1 if q2 fails? and how `conn.rollback()` helps? Will the `conn.commit()` rollback without the need of `rollback()`?

   ```
   Connection conn=getConnection();
   try{
      executesSomeQuery(conn); // has three queries in order; q1, q2, q3. q2 fails and causes error
      conn.commit();
   } catch(Exception e){
      //assume exception is thrown because commit failed due to q2
      conn.rollback();
   }
   ```

Comment: not really java related, this is just standard database behavior, but what happens if you test it? (rollback after commit does nothing, there is nothing to rollback after it is committed)

Comment: I feel like the answer to this question is a google away...

Comment: See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rollback_(data_management))

Comment: You'd usually put the `rollback()` in the catch block, not in the `finally`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Commit and rollback inform the database to commit or rollback (i.e. undo) the current transaction. At the Java level, they don't actually do much at all.

How it's done on the database varies on the actual database implementation.

In your case, if q2 fails, whatever effects q1 had on the database will be undone.

And, naturally, q3 won't be executed at all.

Answer (score 3):

As the name suggests, rollback() rolls back transaction and does not make any change to the database.

All the statements in your try block get executed sequentially on DB. If any of them throws an exception the code does not commit the changes, instead, it reverts them all and leaves the DB in the unimpacted state.

This helps to achieve Atomicity for multiple transactions.

Answer (score 2):

The idea of the rollback is that, whenever you are inserting/updating data in the database, if there are any errors rollback will save you from inserting/updating wrong/not complete data into the database. By looking at your code snippet 1- is wrong, you should rollback in the catch, if the error is caught than rollback must happen, finally is last in execution so by that time data is already committed, there is nothing to rollback.